# Mirror image but keep translate stable

Tags: css

When I flipped the image, also transform: translate in goes the reverse direction.
How to achieve a mirror image in the current translated position?

```css
img {
  transform: translate(50px, 100px);
  /* scale:-1; */
}
```

```html
<img class="draggable" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634__340.png" width=200>
```

Since image is dragging with a function and updated transform dynamicaly  expecting to find different than this solution -> transform: translate(50px, 100px) scale(-1);

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need `transform`-property anymore, as far as I know, you could just do:

```css
img {
  translate: 50px 100px;
  scale: -1 1;
}
```

```html
<img class="draggable" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634__340.png" width=200>
```

The `scale`-property takes up to 3 values, corresponding to the 3 axis (x,y,z).
If only 1 value is provided it takes that for both x- and y-axis. That's why you can give it to values, first one for the x-axis, second one for the y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

solved by wrapping scaled element with another div

```css
img {
  scale: -1 1; 
}
.img-wrapper{
  transform: translate(50px, 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper draggable">
<img class="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634__340.png" width=200>
</div>
```